# Bitmap после парсинга из массива байтов не совпадает по хэшу и Equals

Tags: c#, bitmap, bytearray

```
        // Bitmap is an instance of System.Drawing.Bitmap
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();

            using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream(bitmapData))
            {
                var bmap2 = Image.FromStream(ms2) as Bitmap;
                bmap2.Equals(Bitmap); // false
            }
        }
```

Ну почему false?

Comment: Большинство ссылочных типов не сравниваются по содержимому. Bitmap видимо в их числе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж, Equals в Bitmap не переопределен, и поэтому сравнивает ссылки, а объекты тут разные. Чтобы сравнить два Bitmap, я перевел их в массив байтов, затем байты в строки и наконец сравнил эти строки.

```
using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mo1.Bitmap.Save(ms1,ImageFormat.Bmp);
            using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mo2.Bitmap.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                bool b1 = BitConverter.ToString(ms1.GetBuffer()) == BitConverter.ToString(ms2.GetBuffer());
            // b1 is true
            }
        }
```